# How to use custom Spring EL function in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-el

I write a Function like this:

```java
public interface SUtils {

    static String reverseString(String input) {
        StringBuilder backwards = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            backwards.append(input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i));
        }
        return backwards.toString();
    }
}
```

And register this function with `StandardEvaluationContext.registerFunction`.
And in controller I use `@Value("#{#reverseString('hello')}")` can get the value.
but in thymeleaf when I use `${reverseString('hello')}` got an error
`Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "reverseString('hello')"`.

How to use custom spel in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I usually do, is to define Thymeleaf utility classes like this as a Bean using `@Component`. In Spring EL you can then simply refer to them using `@` with auto-detection. So there is no need to register them.

```
@Component
public interface SUtils {

  static String reverseString(String input) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

```
<span th:text="${@sUtils.reverseString('hello')}"></span>
```

Comment: Explaination due to a wrong edit: You refer to a bean in Spring EL using its name, not its class. A `@Component` of the class `SUtils` has the (automatically generated) name `sUtils`. That's why `@sUtils` is correct and `@SUtils` is not.

Comment: Sounds like a neat solution but somehow it doesn't work for me. It *does* work when I change `SUtils` to a `class`. Perhaps because I'm running Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Not in front of a way to test, but offhand try using the static call:

`th:text="${T(com.package.SUtils).reverseString('hello')}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Bean in your config or application class, like this

```
@Bean(name = "sUtils")
public SUtils sUtilsBean() {
    return new SUtils();
}
```